# Qt call custom sub target from top level

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have a Qt 5.8 project that uses [SUBDIRS](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) and one of the sub targets has a [custom target](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) something similar to this:

main.pro:

```
SUBDIRS = subtarget
```

subtarget.pro:

```
mytarget.target = .buildfile
mytarget.commands = touch $$mytarget.target
mytarget.depends = mytarget2

QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
```

Generating the Makefiles from this using qmake will correctly add my custom target in the subtargets Makefile. However I would like to call it from the toplevel Makefile such that I could just call "make mytarget" from the top level. Note that this custom target is not supposed to be run by default, only explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to define a target with the same name in the toplevel project, and tell qmake that this target should call subtargets as well. This can be done by adding the following lines to main.pro:

```
mytarget.target = .buildfile
mytarget.CONFIG += recursive
mytarget.recurse_target = .buildfile
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += mytarget
```

I case you have multiple subprojects, this target must be present in all of them. You can create dummy targets for projects that don't have such a target as follows:

```
dummyTarget.target = .buildfile
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += dummyTarget
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked. But I got into a problem that the other subtargets that needed the dummys had some PRE_TARGETDEPS set and apparently the dummy target errors when it can't find that.

Comment: Can you show the code/error log? I'm not shure what you mean